# How to get Perticular character from String based on value in Java?

Tags: java, string

Here i have String base="flames" and value will be dynamic.Based on values i need to get the character from base string.if value=0 i need to get output 'f' and if value more than 6 then i need to start 'f as 7' then print particular value.If value=10 then i need to get output as 'm'.Can anybody help me how to get this.This is my code.

```
public class demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String base = "FLAMES";
    int value = 6;
    if (base.length() >= value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
 }
}
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please tell me why vote down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String base = "FLAMES";
        int value = 1;
        value--;
        value = value % base.length();
        System.out.println(base.charAt(value));
     }
```

You can use modulus division in case the value is larger than the length of the string.  This will give you the character for any input. Just add 1 to number I edited my post.

Comment: brso05,if to get correct one(i mean)if value=1 how can i get 'F' and value=6 how can i get 'S' and so on...

Comment: @GangadharB just add 1 to number before modulus division. I edited my answer.

Comment: brso05,10 should give me 'M' could you please help me.

Comment: brso05,why someone down voted my question.can you tell me if possible.So that i will rectify.

Comment: @GangadharB I don't know why they downvoted.  I upvoted it though.

Answer (score 2):

Try mod operator:

```
int value = 6;
System.out.println(base.charAt(value % base.length()));//F
value = 7;
System.out.println(base.charAt(value % base.length()));//L
```

Remember You are saying 0 should give you F, so 10 would give you E and not M as below

`F L A M E S F L A M  E S`
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11`

Comment: almas shaikh,if to get correct one(i mean)if value=1 how can i get 'F' and value=6 how can i get 'S'

Comment: almas shaikh,10 should give me 'M' could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`String` - String is character array in java, and array always start with zero index.

```
F   L   A   M   E   S  
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

But, as per your question you need

```
    0 => F  
    7 => F  // String length is 6, but array index start from 0.
   10 => M
```

Modified Code : Here I have manged index if the value is greater then 7.

```
public class demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String base = "FLAMES";
    int value = 10;  // get input 
    char c=base.charAt(value%base.length());  

    if(value>=7){ // if value exceeds the 6, 
        value = value-1;  // you have to do value-1 to manage index.
        c=base.charAt(value%base.length());
    }

    System.out.println("char : "+c);  // print result
 }
```